# CPU RAM keeps increasing in every epoch and doesn't free up CPU RAM after every epoch, also doesn't increase much after first epoch

Tags: python, cpu, ram, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

This is my code:

```
class VideoEmbeddingDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, pth_file,labels):
        self.pth_file = pth_file
        self.labels = labels
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
      

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Load and preprocess video
        tensor_path = self.pth_file[index]
        tensor = torch.load(tensor_path)
        label = self.labels[index]
    
        return tensor,label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pth_file)

    def collate_fn(self, batch):
        # Pad frames to match the max length within a batch
        max_frames = max([len(sample[0]) for sample in batch])
    
        padded_tensor=[]
        padded_labels=[]
        for sample in batch:
            tensor, label = sample
            num_padding = max_frames - len(tensor)
            padding_tensor = torch.zeros(num_padding, tensor.shape[1], dtype=tensor.dtype).to(self.device)
            tensor = torch.cat((tensor, padding_tensor), dim=0) if num_padding > 0 else tensor[:max_frames]
            padded_tensor.append(tensor)
            padded_labels.append(label)
        
        #return padded_batch
        return torch.stack(padded_tensor,dim=0),padded_labels


class VideoEmbeddingDataLoader(DataLoader):
def __init__(self, pth_file,labels, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, pin_memory = False):
    self.dataset = VideoEmbeddingDataset(pth_file,labels)
    super().__init__(self.dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=num_workers,collate_fn=self.dataset.collate_fn, pin_memory = False)

batch_size = 2
train_dataloader = VideoEmbeddingDataLoader(train_embedding_files,train_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
val_dataloader=VideoEmbeddingDataLoader(val_embedding_files,val_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
```

In the training process the CPU RAM keeps increasing and doesn't free up after every epoch. To check where the problem is, I tried running this code only :

```
num_epochs = 5
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}')

for i,(embeddings_tensor, batch_labels) in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
    del embeddings_tensor
    del batch_labels
    gc.collect()
```

I have observed that the CPU RAM usage increases continuously even with the given code and it does not get released after every epoch. Additionally, the increase in memory usage is not significant after the first epoch. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening and suggest possible solutions to mitigate this issue.